# Comparable<? super T> together with List<? extends T>?

Tags: java, generics

In the Oracle Java tutorial, I've came across the following method signature:

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>
        T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end)
```

I don't see why we need both `Comparable<? super T>` and `List<? extends T>` - as far as I understand, one of the will do.

Let's say none of them, and the signature would be (omitting the `Object` thingy which is there mainly for compatibility reasons):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>>
        T max(List<T> list, int begin, int end)
```

For the discussion, let's say we have the following 2 classes:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> { // ... }
class Student extends Person
```

If we'd want to call this max method with a list of students, it wouldn't be possible, since `Student` doesn't implement `Comparable<Student>`, it implements `Comparable<Person>`.

One way to solve this is to declare the method as such:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T> T max(List<T> list, int begin, int end)
```

In this case, if we'd call the max method with a list of Students, the inferred type T will be `Student`.

Alternatively, the method signature may be:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end)
```

In this case, the inferred type will be `Person`, but since `List<? extends T>` we can call the method with a list of Students.

So can someone explain - in what scenario do we need both?

Answer (score 2):

> So can someone explain - in what scenario do we need both?

Imagine, you want to pass `List<Student>` as a `list` but want to get `Person` as a return type.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T> T max(List<T> list, int begin, int end)
```

This signature works, the code below successfully compiles:

```
List<Student> list = List.of(new Student());
Person max = max(list, 0, 10);
```

If I change the signature to:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end)
```

The code compiles too.

### `max` returns `Optional`

Now, let's say, you return not `T` but `Optional<T>`.
I change the first signature to:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Optional<T> max(List<T> list, int begin, int end)
```

and the following code won't compile:

```java
List<Student> list = List.of(new Student());
Optional<Person> max = max(list, 0, 10);
```

The `T` is inferred to a `Student`, I assign the `Optional<Student>` to `Optional<Person>`, and the assignment fails.

I fix it with `List<? extends T>`:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Optional<T> max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) {
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student> list = List.of(new Student());
    Optional<Person> max = max(list, 0, 10);
}
```

This is the example where you need both `? super T` and `? extends T`

#### The alternative signature

> Alternatively, the method signature may be:
>
> ```java
> public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end)
> ```

Let's try this signature with `Optional`. I use the following signature of `max`:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Optional<T> max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end)
```

This code compiles:

```java
List<Student> list = List.of(new Student());
Optional<Person> max = max(list, 0, 10);
```

Now, let's imagine, we have a `Student2`:

```java
class Student2 extends Student {
}
```

and I want to a pass a `List<Student2>` as a `list` but get `Optional<Student>` back:

```java
List<Student2> list = List.of(new Student2());
Optional<Student> max = max(list, 0, 10);
```

And the code won't compile: `T` is inferred as a `Person` because we have a restriction that `T extends Comparable<T>`. We have to relax the condition with `T extends Comparable<? super T>` to allow this:

```java
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Optional<T> max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end) {
    return Optional.empty();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student2> list = List.of(new Student2());
    Optional<Student> max = max(list, 0, 10);
}
```

Which again brings us to the signature with both `super` and `extends`